# Galaxy S GT-I9000 is slow

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, performance

My GT-I9000 takes ages to come "alive" after powering up. It has been slow for a while, but now it has gotten even slower, anything up to 10 minutes sometimes. When it activates, everything works fine.

I was wondering if it is the loaded software that is causing the problem. Firmware is Gingerbread 2.3.6 XXJW4/XXJW4/OXAJW5. I have done a full factory reset and cleared the cache, but it does not make any difference. Can anyone help please?

Comment: After the factory reset, and before you installed all your apps again, did it make a difference then?

Comment: Hi,There was no difference after the above. Also, while I was waiting for an answer, I read somewhere else that the XXJW4 is likely to be the problem and would recommend to downgrade to Gingerbread 2.3.4 XXJV7. I have just done that and again, the phone works great with either firmware but after powering off and then on again (no necessarily immediately) the time lag to come on it is not normal.The last time has taken 7 minutes to activate. I am doing all of these tests without my simcard inserted but it is the same with it in.

Comment: If it only happens on power-on, why bother? How often do you power-off/on your device? Hey, it's not a Windows phone which needs a daily reboot! My guess is it re-organizes the Dalvik cache on each boot, as if you'd just installed a fresh ROM. While this slows down the first-time-to-ready, this would result in added snappiness lateron.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem. It went away when I uninstalled the Facebook app.

Comment: In part the performance issues is the older kernel and its default governors and schedulers + touchwiz. After that you will find another app and then another which will severely degrade your devices performance. The best way is to move away from this old official Firmware altogether, except for "flash resetting" purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The official Firmware runs Touchwiz, which is a known Resourcehog, in addition to 2.x having known occasional performance issues with the Mediascanner.

I recommend flashing the latest stable [CyanogenMod release](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=galaxysmtd).

Although you will sacrifice a few features, such as FM Radio - which can be restored with specific Kernels and Apps which use the functionality, it is very much worth the initial time investment in aspects of performance.